# Resend email notification in workflow (not reminder or delay)

Tags: send-email

I have a workflow where various approvers will receive email notifications asking for said approval, and once its given it moves on to the next approver. Unfortunately one of the approvers, a client, is adamant that no such email was received even though it has worked for others. It is difficult to restart the workflow or create new tests due to the nature of the client. So my question is:

Is there some step I can take or button I can press to have the email notification resent so that I can confirm with the client they aren't receiving such emails without having to go through all the previous approvers again?

Not an automatic reminder or delay. I.e. the notification email was supposedly sent by the system, the user said it was not received, I want to see if I can execute an action that would supposedly "send" it again

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

The simplest solution would be to disable the current workflow and create a temporary test workflow that sends an e-mail under the conditions you require. This assumes of course that you are able to turn off the workflow without affecting the system functionality for other users and risk creating a bigger problem.

The more involved solution would be to build some debug conditional statements into a copy of your current workflow. You can then turn the current workflow off and start the replacement workflow with debug logic. In the replacement workflow you could add something like;

If record-ID is record you want to re-test then 
   Insert Block that sends e-mail to specific person for approval
Else
   Run as usual

You can then manually trigger the workflow and see if the user is getting said e-mail.

One other thought is what happens if a users mailbox is full? If you are using Approval workflow, you can specify the re-send frequency by specifying the Duration per Task. If this is exceeded the e-mail will be resent. This will continue to happen until the users mailbox becomes available again.

[image]